# В google-chrome на ubuntu не работает pac файл

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, proxy

В google-chrome на ubuntu не работает pac файл для настройки прокси.Пытался пробросить файл через настройки системы и запуская chrome из терминала с флагом --proxy-pac-url. Ничего не помогает, файл не применяется.

Файл точно написан правильно, в firefox все работает. Как можно исправить эту проблему?